# Save data of Custom Fields in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, custom-fields

I have followed all the steps of [*this guide*](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Custom+Fields+and+JSP+Hooks) to add a custom field in **Liferay**, and able to get the label and text box to enter the data on the account details page (`html\portlet\users_admin\user\details.jsp`).

My code is:

```
<div class="exp-ctrl-holder">
    <liferay-ui:custom-attribute
        className="<%= User.class.getName() %>"
        classPK="<%= 0 %>"
        editable="<%= true %>"
        label="<%= true %>"
        name="Bio"
    />
</div>
```

The problem is that when i save its not populating the field on page. 
When i write anything in my "Bio: input" and i click on save, the page loads and then what I had written is cleared. Why?
What's missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect: `classPK="<%= 0 %>"`.

`classPK` is basically the user's primary-key i.e. `userId`. So while adding the User `classPK` will be zero since there is no user created yet, but when you have saved or are updating, then the User would have a classPK and the custom-field `Bio` you are saving will be associated with that `userId`.

Instead you need to use

```
`classPK="<%= (selUser != null) ? selUser.getUserId() : 0 %>"
```

so that when you save and the User is updated, the Users custom-field would be populated.